# Axes numbers interfere with each other

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I have a plot in Mathematica, and the problem is: the axes numbers of plot interfere with each other. How can I eliminate the middle numbers, For example, "5*10^12, 5*10^13, ..." and keep the main numbers "1*10^12, 1*10^13, ...". is there any other way to solve the problem?

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6SZt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple example, the ticks can be fixed like so.  Referencing code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139047/363) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135774/363).

First, the case showing overlapping labels.

```
f[x_] := x^2 + x^3

{min, max} = {10^-12, 10^-10};

LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, min, max}, Frame -> True,
 BaseStyle -> 18, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Removing alternate labels.

```
xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[min], Log[max]];
xticks[[All, 1]] = Exp@xticks[[All, 1]];
xticks[[All, 2]] = ReplacePart[xticks[[All, 2]],
   Thread[Select[Range@Length@xticks, EvenQ] -> Spacer[{0, 0}]]];

LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, min, max}, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {xticks, Automatic}},
 BaseStyle -> 18, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exact answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to keep all the tick labels and rotate them:

```
xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[min], Log[max]];
xticks[[All, 1]] = Exp@xticks[[All, 1]];
xticks[[All, 2]] = Rotate[#, Pi/2] & /@ xticks[[All, 2]];

LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, min, max}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {xticks, Automatic}}, BaseStyle -> 18, 
 FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

[image]